# Java: check if value is 100 or 200 or 300 or x00

Tags: java

In java, I increase a value in a `while` statement and I would like to perform an action when this value has specific values (without hardcoding it because it can in theory go to infinite):

100, 200, 300, x00, etc.

I know this has a specific name, but I cannot remember it (Modulo ? But if so, how ?).

Comment: if(value % 100 == 0) {//do fancy things;}

Comment: I think you're looking for `%`, the remainder operator.

Comment: It's the modulus or remainder operator `%`, you can check examples here https://www.baeldung.com/modulo-java and here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

Comment: Note that `0 % 100 == 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modulo (`%`) operation computes the remainder of a division operation. When `a % b` is 0, that means that `a` is divisible by `b`. Therefore, you could accomplish your task with an if statement with the condition `number % 100 == 0`.

You can find more details about arithmetic operators in the [oracle java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) and the [java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3).